# Automatically create record in table when another table gets a new record

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created the following two classes:

```
public class QuoteGeneral
{
    public int QuoteGeneralID { get; set; }
    public QuoteStatus Status { get; set; }

    //Code and annotation removed for clarity        

    public int? QuoteCustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual QuoteCustomer QuoteCustomer { get; set; }

    public virtual QuoteProduction QuoteProduction { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteProduction
{
    public int QuoteGeneralID { get; set; }

    public int testrun { get; set; }

    public virtual QuoteGeneral QuoteGeneral { get; set; }
}
```

And then I added:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuoteProduction>()
            .HasKey(e => e.QuoteGeneralID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<QuoteGeneral>()
                    .HasOptional(s => s.QuoteProduction)
                    .WithRequired(ad => ad.QuoteGeneral);
```

To set the `QuoteProduction.QuoteGeneralID` field to be both the primary and foreign key. So, now when the database is generated it will look something like:

[image]

I would like a record to be automatically created in the `QuoteProduction` table whenever one is entered into the `QuoteGeneral` table. Is this possible? Or, do I have to add it myself? If I do have to add it myself, what is the best way of capturing the `QuoteGeneralID` value? I don't think `SELECT MAX(QuoteGeneralID) FROM QuoteGeneral` will always be reliable since I may have a lot of users working with the database, and it may pull the wrong value.

**EDIT: What worked for me (for reference to possibly help other in the future)**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "list of bind fields")] QuoteGeneral quoteGeneral)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.QuoteGenerals.Add(quoteGeneral);

        var qp = new QuoteProduction
        {
            QuoteGeneralID = quoteGeneral.QuoteGeneralID
        };

        db.QuoteProductions.Add(qp);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(quoteGeneral);
}
```

Comment: Use a INSERT trigger on your QuoteGeneral table

Comment: use after insert triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the QuoteGeneralID is a foreign key into the QuoteGeneral table you can simply create the QuoteProduction record:

```
var qp = new QuoteProduction
{
    QuoteGeneral = quoteGeneral
};
```

The `quoteGeneral` object doesn't have to have been saved first.

Then when you save the `quoteGeneral` record the associated `QuoteProduction` record will get saved at the same time.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like a record to be automatically created in the QuoteProduction table whenever one is entered into the QuoteGeneral table.

```
Create trigger trg_test
on dbo.QuoteGeneral
after insert 
as
begin

Set nocount on

insert into dbo.QuoteProduction
select requiredcolumns
from
inserted i

End
```

Comment: Can triggers be created using code first in visual studio? Or will I have to add the trigger to the database manually?

Comment: +1 for a valid solution. However, I don't want to have to manually create the trigger if the database is dropped and recreated during the development phase.

Answer (score 0):

After you do .SaveChanges() you should be able to get the id of that object and then use that to add the child table.